# jQuery add form input and change input name

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I'm constructing a order form for a wedding photographer, so guests can order pictures from within the client album section of his site.

Guests order between 1 and 50 pictures, so I'm currently using jQuery's `clone()` function, which is working great.

However I also need to change the name attr of each input, each time I add one so the form processing can pick up on the new inputs.

```
name="picture-1"
add field
name="picture-2"
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I believe I can use `addClass()` each time `clone()` is called, but how can I make `addClass()` to count?

Thank you

Comment: better to use `<input name="picture[]" />` if server side language is **PHP**

Comment: @diEcho: **If** you're using PHP on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just set the `name` property of the cloned element. (<s>Using `prop` on jQuery 1.6 or above; `attr` on 1.5.2 and below.</s> Looks like `attr` works on both 1.5 and 1.6; `prop` *also* works on 1.6 and above.)

But note that the way HTML forms work, it's fine to have multiple fields with the same *name*, they are all sent to the server, where your code can process all of them (usually the server-side technology you're using sets them up as an array or list).

Example:

HTML:

```
<form id='theForm'>
  <input type='text' name='picture-1'>
  <input type='button' id='btnMore' value='+'>
</form>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('#btnMore').click(function() {
  var form, fields, newField;

  form = $("#theForm");
  fields = form.find("input[name^='picture-']");
  newField = $(fields[0]).clone();
  newField.attr('name', 'picture-' + (fields.length + 1));
  newField.insertAfter(fields.last());
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/equvu4)

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder, I didn't even think about using attr.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name^="picture-"]',pointertoform).length
```

...will give you the number of actually present input's with a name starting with "picture-", you may use this number to create the new name.

But I would prefer the solution of diEcho's comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this ( raw code)

```
$(some_cloned_element).each(function(i, elem){
    var newName = "yay_i_love_my_new_name";
    if ($.browser.msie === true){ // evil browser sniffing *cries*
        $(elem).replaceWith(document.createElement(
            this.outerHTML.replace(/name=\w+/ig, 'name='+newName+'_'+i)
        ));
    } else {
        $(elem).attr('name',newName+'_'+i);
    }
    $("body").append(some_cloned_element);
});
```

check when **i=50** and then *break/exit*

**better way :** use name as array like `name=picture[]`

[Refernece](http://www.danconnor.com/dynamic-name-input-attributes-with-ie-and-jquery-clones.html)